# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: 100

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv

I had a long time to fix this issue but couldn't solve it.
I was sure there were no wrong codes, but if I execute the emulator then the problem is when I click the specific item on the listview, it is shown, "open app again". I made database and put datas in it from csv file. Here are the codes:

> word_db.csv

[word_db.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF6xc.png)

> DB_Word.java

```
public class DB_Word extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DB_Word(Context context){
    super(context, "word.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists word (word_id integer primary key, category_id_fk integer, word_kor text, word_eng text, word_pro text, foreign key(category_id_fk) references category(category_id));");
    System.out.println("Create table word success");
}

@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table word;");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

> Categories_wordview1.java

```
public class Categories_wordview1 extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter;
ListView wordlist;

DB_Word dbc;
SQLiteDatabase db;

String sql;
Cursor cursor;
String[] result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_wv);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    wordlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordlist);
    dbc = new DB_Word(this);

    delete();
    insertAll();
    select();
}

public void delete(){
    try {
        System.out.println("delete complete");
        db = dbc.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from word;");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void select(){
    System.out.println("select");
    try {
        System.out.println("select try");
        db = dbc.getReadableDatabase();
        sql = "select word_kor, word_eng, word_pro from word;";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        result = new String[count];

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            System.out.println("select for");
            cursor.moveToNext();
            String str_kor = cursor.getString(0);
            String str_eng = cursor.getString(1);
            String str_pro = cursor.getString(2);
            result[i] = str_kor + "  " + str_eng + "  " + str_pro;
        }

        Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        wordlist.setAdapter(Adapter);
        wordlist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void insertAll(){
    System.out.println("insert");

    db = dbc.getWritableDatabase();
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word_db);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String tableName ="word";
    String columns = "word_id, category_id_fk, word_kor";
    String str1 = "insert into " + tableName + "(" + columns + ") values(";
    String str2 = ");";
    String line ="";

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        System.out.println("transaction try");
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("transaction while");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
            String[] str = line.split(",");
            sb.append(str[0] + ", ");
            sb.append(str[1] + ", '");
            sb.append(str[2] + "'");
            sb.append(str2);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            db.execSQL(sb.toString());
            //db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

}

> Here is the logcat showing:

```
12-28 00:04:05.106 1554-1651/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
12-28 00:04:15.182 1554-1795/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.project2/.Categories_word.Categories_wordview1} from uid 10009
12-28 00:04:15.194 1380-2231/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 3729276 , only wrote 3728880
12-28 00:04:15.315 3259-3259/? I/System.out: delete complete
12-28 00:04:15.401 3259-3259/? I/System.out: Create table word success
12-28 00:04:15.409 3259-3259/? I/System.out: insert
12-28 00:04:15.411 3259-3259/? I/System.out: transaction try
12-28 00:04:15.412 3259-3259/? I/System.out: transaction while
12-28 00:04:15.412 3259-3259/? I/System.out: insert into word(word_id, category_id_fk, word_kor) values(﻿100, 100, '안녕하세요');
12-28 00:04:15.413 3259-3259/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ﻿100
12-28 00:04:15.413 3259-3259/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-28 00:04:15.418 3259-3259/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.project2, PID: 3259
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project2/com.example.project2.Categories_word.Categories_wordview1}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ﻿100 (code 1): , while compiling: insert into word(word_id, category_id_fk, word_kor) values(﻿100, 100, '안녕하세요');
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ﻿100 (code 1): , while compiling: insert into word(word_id, category_id_fk, word_kor) values(﻿100, 100, '안녕하세요');
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                     at com.example.project2.Categories_word.Categories_wordview1.insertAll(Categories_wordview1.java:117)
                                                     at com.example.project2.Categories_word.Categories_wordview1.onCreate(Categories_wordview1.java:51)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
12-28 00:04:15.483 1554-1566/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.project2/.Categories_word.Categories_wordview1
12-28 00:04:15.503 1554-1566/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.project2/.Categories
```

This is the issue:

E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ﻿100

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ﻿100 (code 1): , while compiling: insert into word(word_id, category_id_fk, word_kor) values(﻿100, 100, '안녕하세요');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your CSV file contains an invisible control character (zero width no-break space) that is written by some Windows programs to mark the file as containing Unicode. Remove it.